# Alternative to Quicksilver Triggers

Tags: finder, spotlight, quicksilver

Well after using QS for quite some time, it no longer works...Even when loading it on a clean SL build with latest Apple updates.  When I set up a trigger they will only work until I reboot.  At that point none of the trigger action works.

I heavily use(d) custom triggers and I am not having any luck finding a alternative to QS with that functionality.  Do custom triggers only exist in QS or are there alternatitives?

**EDIT**

Just thought I would add the problem descibed with triggers is known with b58 and now with the latest b59.  So if b59 is not even on blacktree's site and only on qsapp.com (as someone posted), meaning brand new I guess the next hope is b60.  Who knows when that may be available though.

Comment: Are all of your triggers simply launching apps from keypresses? FastScripts by Red Sweater is perfect for mapping keypresses to scripts http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/ A one line applescript could be written for each app you want to launch.

Answer (score 2):

You are not alone in this problem and in fact I bought [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) as part of addressing this problem.

It looks like there are some other users still trying to get Quicksilver working, and even though it is not really in active development, there is an [article on how to download two different versions of Quicksilver, and then selectively deleting or merging files together](http://www.appledoes.com/quicksilver-and-snow-leopard-finally-work-hand-in-hand.html).

Honestly, given this level of annoyance, I would go with Alfred.

Comment: Yeah I got Alfred about an hour ago and have been using it as I rebuild my machine.  It is a great app and I am sure I will continue to use it but really bummed about not have an app launcher with custom triggers.

Comment: Yeah, there is a thread on getsatisfaction on that right now http://getsatisfaction.com/alfredapp/topics/keyboard_triggers , I dont know if they will ever have as good of support for triggers as quicksilver :(

Comment: Cool looks like Alfred will be adding the core of the functionality.  QS was extremely easy and Alfred may require some more work for custom triggers, but hey if QS is dead I will happily work with this other alternative.

Comment: Just want to mention that QS is still under an active development. Although backtree no longer maintain QS, it was given to opensource community and now is hosted at [GitHub](https://github.com/quicksilver/Quicksilver). From the [commit logs](https://github.com/quicksilver/Quicksilver/commits/master) and [Issue page](https://github.com/quicksilver/Quicksilver/issues) there you'd have a sense of how active they are.

Answer (score 2):

Guys, Quicksilver has just been updated (!!!).

http://qsapp.com/

Commence rejoicing.

Comment: hmmm blacktree is still hosting b58 as the latest and no reference to b59.  that link you post doesn't show up near the top of a search on QS so I never would have found it.

Comment: well just loaded up b59 and the same problem exist that I mentioned in my original post.  man i got excited for a min. maybe i will come back with b60

Comment: Not sure what's the specific problem you have but several trigger-related bugs has been fixed since b59 and they will be available in b60.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Launchbar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) for several years after getting frustrated with QuickSilver's lack of updates. It is rock solid and I have never had an issue with a system update breaking it. I would give it a big thumbs up.

Comment: The problem with LaunchBar (which is terrific and I use it on one of my Macs) is that it is a great QuickSilver replacement except that it doesn't do what the original poster wants, which is triggers from the keyboard. So with LB, you can't, for example, hit F5 to launch Mail.